# Google Chrome - net-export logs - Waiting for available sockets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My web app recently moved to HTTP2 protocol, and since then the web pages et stuck at Waiting_for_available_socket randomly and nothing works till either browser is closed or sockets are flushed manually.

net-export logs show that there are already 6 open sockets (max per domain) and corresponding HTTP2_sessions.

[image]

It seems that these sessions are sitting ideal for some time (big gap between st).

But chrome is neither using these sessions for next request nor closing these. Thus new requests are waiting for sockets to be available. (SOCKET_POOL_STALLED_MAX_SOCKETS_PER_GROUP)
[image]

Web app works fine in firefox, why is it a problem in chrome?